# How to create a placeholder text in JQuery Select2 Plugin with selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, placeholder

I'm able to create a placeholder text in Select2 just fine. However the placeholder text is only shown when the selection is empty (that is, until the user has selected some value).

I'd like to somehow instruct users that multiple values are allowed by showing something like "Enter next value" as placeholder text **after** the already previously selected values.

Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, you may use more verbose phrase like `enter one or more values` or just `enter values`, that's enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

Like commented from AFAIK it is not possible.

But you could try a work around for solving this problem using the placeholder and allowClear attributes. In this case after selecting the first item the select2 will present to you a clear button that you can substitute dynamically with your text like in the following demo:

```js
$(function() {
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state",
    allowClear: true
});
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").on("select2:select", function (e) {
    $(".select2-selection__clear").text("Enter next value or Clear");
});
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
    $(".select2-selection__clear").text("Enter next value or Clear");
});
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 248px;">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a `selected` attribute to the `<option>` tag should achieve the desired effect.